# What's wrong with running a live site from a DVCS clone?

Tags: deployment, dvcs

I see insinuations here and there that it's bad to run a live deployment directly off a DVCS clone, and better to export a clean tree or tarball and deploy that. It seems to me that running directly from a DVCS clone has several advantages:

1. No need to transport the entire codebase on every deployment.
2. Trivial to update code to any desired version.
3. Trivial to rollback to previous version if deployment goes badly.

And I can't really see any disadvantages. The presence of the repo files (in my case, a single .hg/ directory) causes no problems.

Is there really any good reason not to run a live deployment off a DVCS clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I do. The only "disadvantage" is you can't really version-control the databases or site-generated content (user uploads). It's not a disadvantage at all though because there's no alternative. Just as usual, you need a backup script to copy all that content out.

This isn't an answer but rather an explanation of modern webapp directory layouts. A very simple Python webapp might look something like this:

```
webapp/
  .hg/
  webroot/
  handler.py
```

You would set it up so that the webserver only serves static content from `webroot/` and if the path doesn't exist in there it asks python (in this case) for that page.

Since none of the server-side source-code is within `webroot/`, it cannot be served (unless you have a python directive ordering it to serve source code). The same applies to the `.hg/` directory.

**Note:** SVN (< 1.7) and CVS are exceptions as they *spray* their `.svn` directories over every subdirectory. In this case that would include `webroot/` so, yes, you'd need to make sure you weren't serving hidden files but this is commonly the case anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know of one.

If someone can gain access to your .hg directory, they could potentially view your source code. But really, access to this directory should be disallowed by the server or by .htaccess files.

Comment: In any modern web-dev stack I know of (barring PHP, which I don't use), the web app source code is not in a web-viewable directory anyway. So this is only relevant if you work in PHP.

Comment: You're missing the point. If somebody will find the way to get your .hg directory they will have entire history of your project and all your sources. So they can steal it and use this knowledge for free.

Comment: bialix, you're missing the point. Look at my answer for an explanation on how modern webapps structure their files - the `.hg` dir will never be served as it's not within the web root.

Comment: I don't think I'm missing the point. I work in modern dynamic-language web-app stacks. The source code is always on the server, but never in a web-accessible directory. I don't see how an attacker getting my version history is worse than an attacker getting the current deployed version.